# Constructor.newInstance with Object[] argument

Tags: java

I have been programming java a long time and for some reason I am unable to figure out why this gives me an argument type mismatch.  I created a very simple JUnit test anyone can run.  Just copy and paste the code below.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

    import org.junit.Test;



    public class TestObjectArrayConstructor {
        @Test
        public void testLabelValueObjectArrayConstructor(){
            Constructor constructor = null;
            try {
                constructor = LabelValue.class.getConstructor(
                        new Class[]{Object[].class});
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Object[] array = new Object[]{"Doll"};
            Object labelValue = null;
            try {
                labelValue = constructor.newInstance(array);
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("don");
        }
    }



public class LabelValue {
    private String label;
    private String value;

    public LabelValue(){

    }

    public LabelValue(Object[] array)
    {
        if(array != null && array.length > 0)
        {
            this.label = (String)array[0];
            this.value = (String)array[0];
        }
    }


    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (not tested) :

```
constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{array});
```

because newInstance expects an array of Object (the different args), and your case is ambiguous, as your param is an array of Object.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure out what I was trying to do. When I modified the test and this worked I realized what you were saying is correct.  labelValue = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{new Object[]{"Doll"}});

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a `newInstance` from a `constructor`then you need to pass your actual parameters, in your case a single argument `array` as `new Object[]`:
replace

```
labelValue = constructor.newInstance(array);
```

with

```
labelValue = constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{array});
```